# How to Increase Query Speed

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

i am trying to speed up some query in postgresql, currently i think is slow, considering that i want to get by date range, currently i have this:

```
select enc.inputdatetime::date dateMed, enc.transmissioncode,
   max(det.devicelevel) devicelevel, max(det.pressure) pressure,
   max(det.battery) battery,enc.remotelocationid,max(det.loop1con) loop1con 
from tl.tlinputdetail det 
inner join tl.tlinputtable enc on det.oldmedicionid = enc.oldmedicionid 
   where TRIM(enc.transmissioncode)= '005'
   and enc.inputdatetime::date between '2015-12-12' and '2016-11-12'                           
group by 
   enc.transmissioncode,enc.remotelocationid,enc.inputdatetime::date
order by 
   enc.inputdatetime::date asc;
```

> Total query runtime: 47.6 secs 60 rows retrieved.

How can i increase my query?, i have index in both tables, in oldmedicionid column, transmissioncode, and inputdatetime

**Query Explain**

```
"Sort  (cost=105519.94..105519.96 rows=7 width=30)"
"  Sort Key: ((enc.inputdatetime)::date)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=105519.76..105519.85 rows=7 width=30)"
"        Group Key: (enc.inputdatetime)::date, enc.transmissioncode, enc.remotelocationid"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..105517.50 rows=129 width=30)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tlinputtable enc  (cost=0.00..104881.30 rows=64 width=31)"
"                    Filter: (((inputdatetime)::date >= '2015-12-12'::date) AND ((inputdatetime)::date <= '2016-11-12'::date) AND (btrim((transmissioncode)::text) = '005'::text))"
"              ->  Index Scan using tlinputdetail_oldmedicionididx on tlinputdetail det  (cost=0.43..9.90 rows=4 width=15)"
"                    Index Cond: (oldmedicionid = enc.oldmedicionid)"
```

**Detailed explain, analyze, verbose**

```
 "Sort  (cost=105519.94..105519.96 rows=7 width=30) (actual time=57948.774..57948.782 rows=61 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((enc.inputdatetime)::date), enc.transmissioncode, (max((det.devicelevel)::text)), (max((det.pressure)::text)), (max((det.battery)::text)), enc.remotelocationid, (max((det.loop1con)::text))"
"  Sort Key: ((enc.inputdatetime)::date)"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=105519.76..105519.85 rows=7 width=30) (actual time=57948.655..57948.717 rows=61 loops=1)"
"        Output: ((enc.inputdatetime)::date), enc.transmissioncode, max((det.devicelevel)::text), max((det.pressure)::text), max((det.battery)::text), enc.remotelocationid, max((det.loop1con)::text)"
"        Group Key: (enc.inputdatetime)::date, enc.transmissioncode, enc.remotelocationid"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..105517.50 rows=129 width=30) (actual time=21.621..57708.114 rows=62181 loops=1)"
"              Output: (enc.inputdatetime)::date, enc.transmissioncode, enc.remotelocationid, det.devicelevel, det.pressure, det.battery, det.loop1con"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tl.tlinputtable enc  (cost=0.00..104881.30 rows=64 width=31) (actual time=0.143..1641.444 rows=20727 loops=1)"
"                    Output: enc.inputid, enc.inputdatetime, enc.packagesqty, enc.remotelocationid, enc.transmissioncode, enc.oldmedicionid"
"                    Filter: (((enc.inputdatetime)::date >= '2015-12-12'::date) AND ((enc.inputdatetime)::date <= '2016-11-12'::date) AND (btrim((enc.transmissioncode)::text) = '005'::text))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2556266"
"              ->  Index Scan using tlinputdetail_oldmedicionididx on tl.tlinputdetail det  (cost=0.43..9.90 rows=4 width=15) (actual time=2.467..2.699 rows=3 loops=20727)"
"                    Output: det.inputdetailid, det.inputid, det.devicelevel, det.pressure, det.battery, det.inputdatetime, det.devicecontrol, det.volumecon, det.pressurevolumecon, det.weightcon, det.decimalunit, det.weightunitcon, det.loop1con, det.loop2co (...)"
"                    Index Cond: (det.oldmedicionid = enc.oldmedicionid)"
"Planning time: 0.549 ms"
"Execution time: 57948.902 ms"
```

Comment: Can you provide the Explain plan?

Comment: sure, i have added this

Comment: the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` would be more helpful. You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Thanks, i will read, i just include the query explain

Comment: The statistics on `tl.tlinputdetail` seem to be out of date. Postgres expects 64 rows, but it contains 20727 . Does the plan change after running `analyze tl.tlinputdetail`

Comment: Looks to me like you could use a partial index on `tl.tlinputtable` where `transmissioncode` = '005'.

Comment: well the transmisssioncode '005' is not static, for the purpose of explanation i use it, but it is dynamically

Comment: I would consider a multi-column index on `transmissioncode` and `tlinputtable` then. Depending on how the data shakes out in practice one ordering may work better than the other; I'd try it both ways and see which is more helpful.

Comment: If you _do_ have an index on `transmissioncode` it won't be used due to the usage of the `trim()` function. Why do you need that? If you can't get rid of it, you need to create the index on `trim(transmissioncode)` in order to match your query condition. But a combined index on `(transmissioncode, inputdatetime)` is probably a good thing to start

Comment: inputdatetime is a timestamp field or did I miss something? you should try to create   index on inputdatetime "CREATE INDEX  ON tl.tlinputtable ((inputdatetime ::date) ASC NULLS LAST);"

Comment: you could also try to increase column target statistics on tlinputtable.oldmedicionid to get better statistics and estamitates. expected 64 rows instead of several thousands sometimes is worry-some

Answer (score 2):

As I see from explain,  tlinputdetail is a device table , tlinputtable is log like table which contains actual main data. Explain shows that only index used is on tlinputdetail and the reason that query is slow is that no filter condition does use any kind of index and database is forced to use sequence scan on the tlinputtable, which I assume is quite large table. To optimise this query you should create 2 indexes:
on inputdatetime as

```
CREATE INDEX ON tl.tlinputtable ((inputdatetime::date) ASC NULLS LAST);
```

and on transmissioncode as

```
CREATE INDEX ON tl.tlinputtable ((trim(transmissioncode)) ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Edit:

for timestamp with timezone as

```
CREATE INDEX ON tl.tlinputtable  (DATE(inputdatetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') ASC NULLS LAST);
```

and use instead something like this this

```
 (date(timezone('UTC'::text, inputdatetime )) between '2015-01-01'::date and ....)
```

use timezone you need instead of UTC

might help [link](http://www.depesz.com/2014/04/04/how-to-deal-with-timestamps/)

Comment: Thanks, running the first query, i got this: "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE", how can i fix that?

Comment: which postgresql version you are using? ah, tlinputtable  must be timestamp with timezone ...

Comment: Is there any chance to change that field to timestamp without timezone?

Comment: no way, that cannot be, and you are right, the inmutable error was because that